# Flutter with Supabase Microsoft Auth

Tags: android, flutter, authentication, supabase

In flutter I have an application that I want to be able to sign with Microsoft:

```dart
// ...
Future<AuthResponse> signInWithMicrosoft() async {
  // Just a random string
  final rawNonce = generateRandomString();
  final hashedNonce = sha256.convert(utf8.encode(rawNonce)).toString();

  /// Client ID that you registered with Microsoft Azure.
  const clientId = '1ecf76c4-433e-43f9-a30f-2c669f031229';

  /// Redirect URI that you registered with Microsoft Azure.
  const redirectUrl =
      'msauth://dev.blueflame.canvas_plus/uUyjEmnuSAzNkfi4rwzLZCKmIVM%3D';

  /// Microsoft OpenID Connect discovery URL.
  const discoveryUrl =
      'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration';

  const appAuth = FlutterAppAuth();

  // authorize the user by opening the concent page
  final result = await appAuth.authorize(
    AuthorizationRequest(
      clientId,
      redirectUrl,
      discoveryUrl: discoveryUrl,
      nonce: hashedNonce,
      scopes: [
        'openid',
        'email',
        'profile',
      ],
    ),
  );

  if (result == null) {
    throw 'No result';
  }

  // Request the access and id token to Microsoft
  final tokenResult = await appAuth.token(
    TokenRequest(
      clientId,
      redirectUrl,
      authorizationCode: result.authorizationCode,
      discoveryUrl: discoveryUrl,
      codeVerifier: result.codeVerifier,
      nonce: result.nonce,
      scopes: [
        'openid',
        'email',
        'profile',
      ],
    ),
  );

  final idToken = tokenResult?.idToken;

  if (idToken == null) {
    throw 'No idToken';
  }

  return supabase.auth.signInWithIdToken(
    provider: Provider.azure,
    idToken: idToken,
    nonce: rawNonce,
  );
}
// ...
```

When I call `signInWithMicrosoft()` it opens an integrated browser that asks for my account, I sign in, and it asks for `Only continue if you downloaded the app from a store or website you trust.` I click continue and it loops back to the same page and doesn't do anything.
Here is my initialization of Supabase in my `main.dart`:

```dart
  await Supabase.initialize(
    url: 'https://hkyajejasstzlneelmwm.supabase.co',
    anonKey:
        'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJzdXBhYmFzZSIsInJlZiI6ImhreWFqZWphc3N0emxuZWVsbXdtIiwicm9sZSI6ImFub24iLCJpYXQiOjE2ODc3NDk5OTEsImV4cCI6MjAwMzMyNTk5MX0.iRJXHt6bjaQ55GOfVzI6Nd5IPMRkUPTVpjjgdauLHoI',
    authCallbackUrlHostname: 'auth',
    debug: true,
  );
```

Here is my `build.gradle`:

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    namespace "dev.blueflame.canvas_plus"
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "dev.blueflame.canvas_plus"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        manifestPlaceholders += [appAuthRedirectScheme: 'canvasplus://account/redirect/']
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

And here is my `manifest.xml`

```xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <application
        android:label="canvas_plus"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.microsoft.identity.client.BrowserTabActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="msauth"
                    android:host="dev.blueflame.canvas_plus"
                    android:path="/uUyjEmnuSAzNkfi4rwzLZCKmIVM%3D" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I am wondering why it doesn't redirect back to my app.

Comment: Generally, try avoiding underscores in URIs. If possible, rename your host to `dev.blueflame.canvasplus`.

Comment: Unfortunately, even after changing it from `dev.blueflame.canvas_plus` to `dev.blueflame.canvasplus` it still results with the same behavior as before.

Comment: Okay, I just realized that you are trying to perform Microsoft login, and not Google login. There could be multiple things that you have to adjust. First, `canvasplus://account/redirect/` that you have set as the appAuthRedirectScheme is not a correct URL scheme. Second, your appAuthRedirectScheme does not match the redirectURL you have in your Flutter code. I'm not very familiar with Microsoft login, so that might not be all the causes. You most likely need to do this while leaving any underscores from URLs as my suggestion from the previous comment.